# multiple buttons in a form

Tags: php, forms, submit

i have in php a table with some rows. Each row contains a dataset with an id. 
The mission is to skip a field in a database depending on the id. The id is unknown.

i plan to skip the dataset with submit buttons. Also each dataset has one button. The form will send to PHP_SELF and in an function i do the update on the database.

Now the challenge is, to find out, which button ist pressed. It is not possible to run trough a case block, because the ids are between 1 and 99999.

can someone help me. I can rename type, name, id, of the buton. The id are already in the rowset.

Thank you very much!
Frank

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
<fieldset><legend>Ihnen zugewiesene Services</legend>
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Schalter</th>
    <th width="100%">Servicename</th>
    <th width="50">Status</th>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <?php if ($row_Recordset1['sendToVoicebox'] == 0) { ?>
        <td><input type="submit" name="<?php $row_Recordset1['service_id']; ?>" id="btnOn" value="Voicebox ein" /></td>
      <?php } else { ?>
        <td><input type="submit" name="<?php $row_Recordset1['service_id']; ?>" id="btnOn" value="Voicebox aus" /></td>
      <?php } ?>          

      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['service_id']; ?></td>

      <?php if ($row_Recordset1['sendToVoicebox'] == 0) { ?>
      <td><img src="images/VoiceboxOff.png" width="64" height="64" alt="pause" /></td>  
      <?php } else { ?>
      <td><img src="images/VoiceboxOn.png" width="64" height="64" alt="pause" /></td>   
      <?php } ?>          
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</table>
</fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1" />
<input name="service_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['service_id']; ?>" />

<?php if ($row_Recordset1['sendToVoicebox'] == 0) { ?>
    <input name="update" type="hidden" value="1" /> 
<?php } else { ?>
    <input name="update" type="hidden" value="0" /> 
<?php } ?>          

</form>
```

how can i catch the id in my function?

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE acdbasis SET userfield_2=%s WHERE service_id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['update'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_REQUEST['submit'], "int"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array

```
<?php if ($row_Recordset1['sendToVoicebox'] == 0) { ?>
<td><input type="submit" name="button[<?php echo $row_Recordset1['service_id']; ?>]" id="btnOn" value="Voicebox ein" /></td>
<?php } else { ?>
<td><input type="submit" name="button[<?php echo $row_Recordset1['service_id']; ?>]" id="btnOn" value="Voicebox aus" /></td>
<?php } ?>

<?php
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
$service_id = array_keys($_POST["button"]);
$service_id = $service_id[0]; //older php versions don't allow direct function...)[key]
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE acdbasis SET userfield_2=%s WHERE service_id=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['update'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($service_id, "int"));
```

Although it isn't very elegant solution I still think it's better than iterating through  $_POST and checking if key is number.

Comment: i use php version 5.3.15. unfortunately, i see in the mysql log always id 0 and i cant understand why?

Comment: ahh, an echo is missing. The correct line is: name="button[<?php echo $row_Recordset1['service_id']; ?>. Can you additional tell me, how i can add a second element $service_id[1] to that variable, because my hidden value isn't working also

Comment: The hidden element and everything after fieldset isn't iterated so it will get $row_Recordset1 from last do…while cycle iteration.
You will get the $service_id from the code in the post above so I don't understand why you need another hidden field.

Comment: hi, your code works fine. i also recognize my failure in the if blocks of hidden fields. for the click i have to do an update of a mysql table. the id is the where filter, the hidden value is the new value. so i have to post 2 digits. for that moment, i work with different button names and isset. My idea is to work with arrays in both cases for clearer code.

Answer (score 0):

How about using PHP `$_GET` array functionality:

```
  <?php if ($row_Recordset1['sendToVoicebox'] == 0) { ?>
    <td><input type="submit" name="service_id[<?php echo $row_Recordset1['service_id']; ?>]" id="btnOn" value="Voicebox ein" /></td>
  <?php } else { ?>
    <td><input type="submit" name="service_id[<?php echo $row_Recordset1['service_id']; ?>]" id="btnOn" value="Voicebox aus" /></td>
  <?php } ?>
```

Form post page:

```
$serviceId = $_POST['service_id'][0]; // Do the work with the service id
```

Or, could you use the value attribute of the button to convey what you want? In addition, you can use the `<button />` tag to show a different value to the customer than what is submitted to the backend:

```
<button type="submit" name="service_submit_id" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['service_id'];?>">Text Here</button>
```

Comment: I think older IEs sent button content instead of value.

Comment: Also your answer is wrong because your HTML code will send `service_id[xx_number]=Voicebox…` generating following structure `$_POST = array('service_id' => array(xx_number => 'Voicebox…'))`.
So your PHP will throw Undefined index notice.